# How to make a histogram from 30 csv files to plot the historgram and then for it with gaussian function and the standard deviation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I want to make a histogram from 30 csv files, and then fit a gaussian function to see if my data is optimal. After that, I need to find the mean and standard deviation of those peaks. The file data size are too large, I do not know if I extract individual column and organize their value range into number of bins correctly.

I know it is a bit long and too many questions, please answer as much as you want, thank you very much!

[> this is the links of the data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vpEA3yP-yrO_JQ_jeOVcTCmtLvN7Ul2U?usp=sharing)

Below so far I have done (actually not much, coz I am beginner to data visualization.)
Firstly, I import the packages, `savgol_filter` to make the bin transparent, it seems better.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
```

And then I convert the dimension and set limit.

```
def cm2inch(value):
    return value/2.54

width = 9
height = 6.75

sliceMin, sliceMax = 300, 1002
```

Next I load all the data jupyter notebook by iteration 30 times, where I set up two arrays "times" and "voltages" to store the values.

```
times, voltages = [], []
for i in range(30):
    time, ch1 = np.loadtxt(f"{i+1}.txt", delimiter=',', skiprows=5,unpack=True)
    times.append(time)
    voltages.append(ch1)    
t = (np.array(times[0]) * 1e5)[sliceMin:sliceMax]
voltages = (np.array(voltages))[:, sliceMin:sliceMax]
```

**1. I think I should need a hist function to plot the graph. Although I have the plot, but I am not sure if it is the proper way to generate the histogram.**

```
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(voltages, bins=500, density=True)
hist = savgol_filter(hist, 51, 3)
bin_centres = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])/2
```

That is so far I have reached. the amplitude of the 3rd peak is too low, which is not what I expected. But please correct me if my expectation is wrong.

[This is my histogram plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbPvv.jpg)

[I have updated my plot with the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIkZr.jpg)

```
labels = "hist"
if showGraph:
    plt.title("Datapoints Distribution over Voltage [mV]", )      
    plt.xlabel("Voltage [mV]")
    plt.ylabel("Data Points")
    plt.plot(hist, label=labels)
    plt.show()
```

**2.(edited) I am not sure why my label cannot display, could you please correct me?**

**3.(edited) Besides, I want to make a fit curve by using gaussian function to the histogram. But there are three peaks, so how should I fit the function to them?**

```
def gauss(x, *p):
A, mu, sigma = p
        return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))
```

**4. (edited) I realised that I have not mentioned the mean value yet.
I suppose that if I can locate the maximum value of the peak, then I can find the mean value of the specific peak. Do I need to fit the Gaussian first to find the peak, or I can find the straight ahead? Is it to find the local maximum so I can find it? If yes, how can I proceed it?**

**5. (edited) I know how to find the standard deviation from a single list, if I want to do similar logic, how to implement the code?**

```
sample = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,10]
standard_deviation = np.std(sample, ddof=1)
print(standard_deviation)
```

---

Feedback to suggestions:
I try to implement the gaussian fit, below are the packages I import.

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Here isthe gaussian function, I put my 30 datasets voltages as the parameter of the Gaussian Mixture fit, which print our lots of values regarding `mu` and `variance`.

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=1)
gmm.fit(voltages)
print(gmm.means_, gmm.covariances_)
mu = gmm.means_[0][0]
variance = gmm.covariances_[0][0][0]
print(mu, variance)
```

I process the code one by one. There is an error on the second line:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
Xs = np.arange(min(voltages), max(voltages), 0.05)
```

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
> Use a.any() or a.all()

I search from the web that, to use this is to indicate there is only one value, like if there are[T,T,F,F,T], you can have 4 possibilities.

I edit my code to:

```
Xs = np.arange(min(np.all(voltages)), max(np.all(voltages)), 0.05)
```

which gives me this:

> 'numpy.bool_' object is not iterable

I understand it is not a boolean object. At this stage, I do not know how to proceed the gaussian curve fit. Can anyone provides me an alternate way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. To plot a histogram, the most vanilla `matplotlib` function, `hist`, is my go-to. Basically, if I have a list of `samples`, then I can plot a histogram of them with `100` bins via:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(samples, bins=100)
plt.show()
```

2. If you'd like to fit normal distribution(s) to your data, the best model for that is a *Gaussian Mixture Model*, which you can find more info about via [scikit-learn's GMM page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html). That said, this is the code I use to fit a singular gaussian distribution to a dataset. If I wanted to fit `k` normal distributions, I'd need to use `n_components=k`. I've also included the resulting plot:

```py
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(800,1))
data += np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(800,1))
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=1)
gmm.fit(data)
print(gmm.means_, gmm.covariances_)
mu = gmm.means_[0][0]
variance = gmm.covariances_[0][0][0]
print(mu, variance)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
Xs = np.arange(min(data), max(data), 0.05)
ys = 1.0/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*variance) * np.exp(-0.5/variance * (Xs + mu)**2)
ax.hist(data, bins=100, label='data')
px = ax.twinx()
px.plot(Xs, ys, c='r', linestyle='dotted', label='fit')
ax.legend()
px.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: plot result]

As for question 3, I'm not sure which axis you'd like to capture the standard deviations of. If you'd like to get the standard deviation of columns, you can use `np.std(data, axis=1)`, and use `axis=0` for row-by-row standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I have edited my post, I hope you could answer my last part? I am now working on your suggestion, hope to get back to you soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above gaussian fit. The 'data' above is for one dataset, I put my 30 datasets 'voltage. An error return: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". I would be better to put into my question so you can view it.

Comment: I try to plot this with another function. I can successfully plot a curve, but not fit to my plot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687843/gaussian-curve-fit-my-curve-does-not-fit-to-my-histogram